# Necessary and sufficient conditions for equivalence of different types of convergences for Bernouli RVs

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let ${X_n}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $Pr(X_n = 1) = p_n$, $Pr(X_n = 0) = 1 - p_n$, where ${p_n}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of numbers in $[0, 1]$.

(a) Give a sufficient and necessary condition on ${p_n}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $X_n\overset{P}{\rightarrow}0$

(b) Give a sufficient and necessary condition on ${p_n}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $X_n\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} 0$.
Prove your claims.

Disclaimer: This is not a exercise. It is a exam preparation question that I was not able to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Some hints:

(a) If $X_n\to 0$ in probability, what should be $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P\{X_n\gt 1/2\}$? What is it in this case?

(b) Notice that since $X_n$ takes the values $0$ and $1$, $X_n(\omega)\to 0$ means that $X_n(\omega)=0$ for $n$ large enough (depending on $\omega$). The key word to find the necessary and sufficient condition is the Borel-Cantelli lemma.